# If A and B are n-th row square matrices, $AB=BA$ and $B^2=0$ prove that $(A+B)^k=A^k+kA^{k-1}B$

Tags: matrices

If A and B are n-th row square matrices, $AB=BA$ and $B^2=0$ prove that  $$(A+B)^k=A^k+kA^{k-1}B$$

Any ideas?

Comment: Idea: use induction on $k$.

Comment: Yes I've tried that and here's what I got:
$$(A+B)^k=A^k+kA^{k-1}B$$

for k=1
$$A+B=A+B$$

for k=k+1
$$(A+B)^k(A+B)=A^k(A+(k+1)B)$$

Answer (score 3):

Proof by induction on $k$.  I leave the base case ($k=1$) for you.

Note that, using the inductive hypothesis, we have $$(A+B)(A+B)^k=(A+B)(A^k+kA^{k-1}B)=A^{k+1}+kA^kB+BA^k+kBA^{k-1}B$$

Now use $BA=AB$ repeatedly to conclude that $BA^k=A^kB$, and $kBA^{k-1}B=kA^{k-1}B^2=0$.

Hence $(A+B)(A+B)^k=A^{k+1}+(k+1)A^kB$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't seem to get it.
I've got:
$$AA^k +kA^kB+BA^k+kBA^{k-1}B$$
$$AA^k +kA^kB+BA^k+kBAA^kB$$
$$AA^k +kA^kB+BA^k+kABA^kB$$

So I haven't really got anything. Where am I supposed to go from here?

Comment: $BA^k=ABA^{k-1}=A^2BA^{k-2}=\cdots=A^{k}B$

Comment: I still don't understand, I'm sorry.

Comment: Write $BA^k$ as $BAAAAAAA$, then move the $B$ along one step at a time $BAAAAAAA=ABAAAAAAA=AABAAAAAA=AAABAAAAA$ etc.

Comment: Right, I see. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Since $A$ and $B$ commute, you can use the binomial formula: for $k\ge 1$,
$$(A+B)^k=A^k +\binom k1 A^{k-1}B +\sum_{i=2}^k\binom kiA^{k-i}\underbrace{B^i}_{=\,0}.$$

Comment: I'm to find a way without using the binomial formula

Comment: You're kidding? This is a basic formula!

Comment: Which is why we're supposed to figure out a way to do it without using it

Comment: And also reinvent the multiplication tables? :o)